# json parsing for inconsistent data

Tags: json, r, parsing, dataframe

I have an excel file that is downloaded from a json database. Here is the sample:

```
df = data.frame("name" = c("John","Jane"), "City" = c("LA","NY"), "Attributes" = c("Edu: ABC; Gender: Male;Language: English","Edu: DEF; Hobby: Cycling; Gender: Female"))
```

the 'Attributes' column contains multiple attributes. not all attributes are present in the rows/observations and not all attributes are in same order.

how can i parse the data into a data frame that looks like this?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxgPXV4CWuSrc2FodlFuckw2Y2s/view?usp=sharing

(This is a dummy data .The actual client data is confidential to share in forum)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may consider working "list wise". Create data frames for each list and then try rbind.fill

Hope this works

Comment: my apologies. i could not understand. could you please rephrase with a bit more elaboration ?